Extracting a String from a [String: Any?] by key
var annoying: [String: Any?]

To get the 'height' value, the best I could come up with is this,
let found: String = (annoying["height"] as? String? ?? "?") ?? "?"


That seems very bad, is there a better way?

Indeed, ideally I'd like
let found: String? = :O


So it's nil if the key does not exist -or- the value is nil -or- the value is not a String - but, I literally, don't know how to do that and every attempt failed :/
(I just make do with the "?" marker in the first solution.)

Something like let found: String? = annoying["height", default: ""] as? String?

You can simply do
let found = annoying["height"] as? String

Requirements

it's nil if the key does not exist

let annoying: [String: Any?] = [:]
let found = annoying["height"] as? String
// nil


-or- the value is nil

let annoying: [String: Any?] = ["height":nil]
let found = annoying["height"] as? String
// nil


-or- the value is not a String

let annoying: [String: Any?] = ["height":42]
let found = annoying["height"] as? String
// nil

And it works for string keys:
let annoying: [String: Any?] = ["height":"10m"]
let found = annoying["height"] as? String
// "10m"

